# Awaiting element load in Angular's scenario runner

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular's scenarios to do end to end testing of my app. I would like to run tests based on elements that take some time to load. I could just use a `sleep()` command, but I'd rather do something like:

```
whenLoaded('p .foo')
    .then(function(elem) { expect(elem.text()).toBe(something); });
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Jasmine.js lets you do that too. Look up async specs.

http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/

```
describe("Asynchronous specs", function() {
  var value, flag;

  it("should support async execution of test preparation and exepectations", function() {
    runs(function() {
      flag = false;
      value = 0;

      setTimeout(function() {
        flag = true;
      }, 500);
    });

    waitsFor(function() {
      value++;
      return flag;
    }, "The Value should be incremented", 750);

    runs(function() {
      expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
  });
});
```